# Codeigniter 3 HMVC wiredesignz showing 404 error

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc, codeigniter-hmvc

I downloaded HMVC files from [here](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/downloads) and set up my CI 3 installation using these file

1. Place the MX folder in application/third_party folder
2. Place the files in application/core MY_Loader & MY_Router
3. $config['modules_locations'] = array(APPPATH.'modules/' => '../modules/',);
4. Created a folder module in application. Inside module created welcome/controller and welcome/view
5. In welcome/controller I copied the default welcome controller and in welcome/view welcome_message.
6. I deleted both files from application/controller and application/view.

Now I am getting 404 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You change name of folder "**module**" to "**modules**".
And in **modules** folder:
You must rename **controller** and **view** folder to **controllers** and **views**.
 Hope this help :)

Comment: Sry my folder name is "**modules**" not "**module**"

Comment: i have been  update my answer! if you wrong that. i hope that help for you

Comment: No problem. But can you vote my answer? Thanks a lot :)